# can the map be updated insetad of returning a new one?

Tags: scala

i noticed there are two methods in the Map trait. + and updated. both do the same, they return a new map with the value changed or added corresponding to the given key.
so, is there a new method i haven't seen that makes sentence 1 or 2 to be true, in order to avoid doing sentence 3

```
var a = Map[Int,Int](1 -> 4, 2 -> 1)
a == a.updated(1,23)  //sentence 1
a == a+(1->23)        //sentence 2
a = a+(1->23)         //sentence 3
```

There may be a discussion why would i want that, im just curious. It is nice to have the constructive form of this, but i wonder about the desctructive version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `scala.collection.mutable.Map`

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
var a = Map[Int, Int](...)
...
```

Comment: i've just imported Map, I didnt pay attention that there where more than 1. Thanks!  I cant vote down my question :S

Comment: Your question is absolutely reasonable. Dont worry :) Does it works?

Comment: Yes it does! Now i am in the philosophical part of which i really need. I really like scala offers me the imperative and the functional version of the same problem :D

Answer (score 2):

The Scala collections library defaults to using immutable versions of collections.  You have to specify the mutable version.

You can just import the mutable Map...

```
scala> import Scala.collection.mutable.Map
scala> Map(1 -> "string")
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> string)
```

Although this then shadows the default Map namespace, making it a little harder to create immutable maps.  You could just always specify the full name each time (`scala.collection.mutable` or `scala.collection.immutable`), which can be made a little easer with a strategic import...

```
umport collection._

val m1: mutable.Map[Int, String] = mutable.Map(1 -> "string")
val m1: immutable.Map[Int, String] = immutable.Map(1 -> "string")
```